# Get Progress and Error operations with the same time on Async functions

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, swift4, alamofireimage

I upload a file with Alamofire in Home VC. But upload func in the class function. So I didnt get the progress operations. I guess I have to write delegate Method.

Anybody will help me?

**My Question is in ViewController !!!**

**In SendPhoto.class**

```
class SendPhoto {


    func send() {
        Alamofire.upload(
        multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
            ...
    },
        to: "",
        headers:headers,
        encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
            switch encodingResult {
            case .success(let upload, _, _):
                upload.uploadProgress {progress in
                    print(progress.fractionCompleted)

                }
                upload.responseJSON { response in

                }
            case .failure(let encodingError):
                print("File Upload Error")
                print(encodingError)
            }
    })
}}
```

**In ViewController**

```
class HomepageVC: UIViewController .. {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }


    @IBAction func sendAction(_ sender: Any) {

        SendPhoto().send()

        // I want to keep this function progress and print to a label or etc. !!!
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to share more detail (e.g some code or scheme)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

However your question is not completed so with assumption

**Alamofire**  returns the **UploadRequest** object on any upload request except multipart request

And upload request has property **progress**

```
/// The progress of fetching the response data from the server for the request.
open var progress: Progress { return dataDelegate.progress }
```

which can be used to track the uploaded progress

**EDIT**

You have to pass data with closure to your view controller

Here is your methdo

```
private func uploadAnyThing  (progress:@escaping ((Progress) -> Void) , completed:@escaping ((_ success:Bool,_ error:Error?) -> Void)) {
    Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (data) in

    }, to: "test.com") { (result) in
        switch (result) {
        case .success(let request, _, _):
            request.uploadProgress(closure: { (prog) in
                progress(prog)
            })

            request.responseJSON(completionHandler: { (res) in
                completed(true,nil)

            })

        case .failure(let error) :
            completed(false,error)
            break
        }
    }
}
```

And you can get it by

```
func test () {
    uploadAnyThing(progress: { (progres) in
        print(progres.fractionCompleted)
    }) { (success, error) in

    }
}
```